# error: Return value transfers ownership but method return type hasn't been declared to transfer ownership

Tags: vala

The following code:

```
public string add_button_tooltip_markup {
    get { return add_button.get_tooltip_markup (); }
    set { add_button.tooltip_markup = value; }
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
error: Return value transfers ownership but method return type hasn't been declared to transfer ownership
        get { return add_button.get_tooltip_markup (); }
```

I'm using Vala 0.40.10.

What's the best way to solve this in Vala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark the getter as owned, as follows:

```
public string add_button_tooltip_markup {
    owned get { return add_button.get_tooltip_markup (); }
    set { add_button.tooltip_markup = value; }
}
```

See the following page for more detail:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling